# warning on Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui package in windows platform

Tags: c#, blazor, maui

i have a .net maui project and i want to add blazor page in my project
when add Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui package from nuget ، All platforms are well supported except Windows and warning sing and displays a warning sign next to it and displays the message "MSB4057 The target "StaticWebAssetsPrepareForRun" does not exist in the project." when running the program.
Please guide me to solve this problem

I don't have a solution for this problem

Comment: Please show relevant code in question (as text not image). https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also, please edit to make this part readable: `and warning sing and displays a warning sign`. Also, did you **google the error messsage**? See https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/2609 for possible fix (change SDK).

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/2609 for possible fix (change SDK):

> Changing project sdk from Microsoft.NET.Sdk to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor resolved the issue.